# Unkown directories in C:\Windows\System32

Tags: windows-10

By chance I opened the C:\Windows\System32 directory and found a large number of files that make no sense to me (see below for a screenshot).

[image]

Within each folder, there is a directory called 'AMD' and one level lower the directory 'DxCache'. As far as I could see, there is nothing in the DxCache directory based on a random sample of these files.

Does anyone know why these directories are being created. Do they have a purpose and can I delete these from my system?

I will appreciate any help or advice on this.

Comment: Have you installed some national-language AMD driver(s) or software? Regardless you can remove those folders freely (especially when they are empty).

Comment: AMD is a graphics card/chip manufacturer. These are likely related to your video drivers.

Comment: Thank you for your advice I am not sure of the source but will remove these.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Following the advice in the comments, I reviewed the files for deletion and decided that this would be quite difficult because there are so many of these unknown directories and risky because there is a a chance of inadvertently deleting the wrong directory.

Consequently, I tried system optimization software available to me (Ashampoo WinOptimizer 16) and fortunately the system cleaning operation deleted most of the unwanted directories. There still are a few of these on the system, but they all appear to have been created today. I believe most of the other system optimization packages like CCleaner etc. also could be used to do the job.

I am not sure why these files were created in the first place, but I am surprised that whatever is creating these doesn't clean up afterwards.

The advice from this forum was appreciated.